# Magento 2.3 CSS inlining error: DOMXPath::query() Invalid expression in selector >> .fotorama__wrap:not(.fotorama__wrap--toggle-arrows)

Tags: magento2, email, css

I am getting this error in Magento 2.3. Error occurs with every email sent.
[image]

```
CSS inlining error: DOMXPath::query(): Invalid expression in selector >> .fotorama__wrap:not(.fotorama__wrap--toggle-arrows) .fotorama__fullscreen-icon << in /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/pelago/emogrifier/src/Emogrifier.php on line 502
```

I have tried this method:

adding this file in app/design/frontend/VendorTheme/default/web/css/email.less

```
@import 'source/lib/email/stand/_lib.less'; // Global lib
@import 'source/lib/email/stand/variables/_email.less'; // Global email variables
```

I have also tried adding

```
"pelago/emogrifier": "1.0.0 as 0.1.1" in composer.json
```

Comment: what is your php version ?

Comment: just downgrade the php version 7.3 to 7.2 every thing is working fine

Answer (score 6):

I have got same error and solved as

Just copy these files:

```
vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/email.less
vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/email-inline.less
```

into:

```
 app/design/frontend/YOUR_VENDOR/YOUR_THEME/web/css/
```

and removed this line from both files `'@import 'source/_theme.less'.`

Cause by doing this we are separating theme css and email css.

Last run the following commands:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Comment: this solution not working so please help me @Rohit Kaushik

Comment: have you removed _theme.less from both files?
/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/email.less
/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/email-inline.less

Answer (score 2):

Please do not use in your css code selectors with :not(), especially if after another selector follows to ':not' .This is necessary to aviod Еmogrifier errrors

Comment: I had this `&:not(:first-child) {` in less and got this error too `Invalid expression in selector >> .email-items tbody dl dt:not(:first-child) `. Not sure if there is any other way to write same css.

Comment: just write styles for all elements '.email-items tbody dl dt' and then  write styles for element '.email-items tbody dl dt:first-child' separately. it would be better

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to fix the issue, is not the best practice, but it works.

Go to Marketing > Email Templates and create a new template. Click on Load template and load Magento_Email > Header.

In the Template Content field remove this line:

```
{{inlinecss file="css/email-inline.css"}}
```

A better solution would be to fix the issue in the file above.

Comment: this will remove css from email template for solution you have to try https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/298985/82482

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
My PHP version: 7.2.32

composer require pelago/emogrifier:2.0.0
```

It was not working with pelago/emogrifier:2.2.0

Thanks,